# How can I group text in a column with based on another column in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm using Python for data analysis/manipulation. To describe what I'm trying to do I posted an example below. To summarize, I extracted a chat from my whatsapp and the messages from a number can be in multiple lines. My goal is to loop through that chat and join the messages from the same number into one line if the message is split in multiple lines. I was trying to do with pandas but I'm a bit lost. Maybe there's another way to do that. Maybe with sqlite?

What I have

|Date     |Username |   Message     |
|:-------:|:-------:|:-------------:|
|11/4/2022|     A   |       Test    |
|11/4/2022|     A   |       123     |
|11/4/2022|     B   |       abc     |
|11/4/2022|     B   |       def     |
|20/4/2022|     A   |       potatoes|
|20/4/2022|     B   |       Tomatoes|
What I Need
|Date     |Username |   Message     |
|:-------:|:-------:|:-------------:|
|11/4/2022|     A   |   Test 123    |
|11/4/2022|     B   |   abc def     |
|20/4/2022|     A   |   potatoes    |
|20/4/2022|     B   |   Tomatoes    |

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an iterative solution, meaning that we loop through some groups. First, we'll group our data by consecutive username as follows:

```
consecutive_groups_df = df.groupby((df['Username'].shift() != df['Username']).cumsum())
```

Now, we will work on each group to aggregate and format the message. Also, we'll represent the group with a single row (as you expect). We'll store the rows and concat all of them in a single dataframe to match your output:

```
out_rows = list()
for _, group_df in consecutive_groups_df:
    out_row = group_df.head(1).copy()  # Copy the first row
    out_row["Message"] = group_df["Message"].str.cat(sep=" ")  # Concatenate messages
    out_rows.append(out_row)  # Save row for later

# Create output dataframe
out_df = pd.concat(out_rows)
```

Output of this code:

```
        Date  Username    Message
0  11/4/2022         A   Test 123
2  11/4/2022         B    abc def
4  20/4/2022         A   potatoes
5  20/4/2022         B   Tomatoes
```